# How does DispatcherServlet decide which View Resolver should be used to resolve logical vie name

Tags: spring-mvc

We can configure more than one view resolver in Spring application context xml file.
Suppose, I have configured InternalResourceViewResolver,TilesViewResolver and XmlViewResolver in my spring application context file. If a request comes for a view named "abc", which view resolver DispatcherServlet choose to resolve this View? What happens,If "abc" view can be resolved by more than one view resolver?

Answer (score 0):

The [official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch16s05.html#mvc-viewresolver-chaining) explains this in detail; each `ViewResolver` has an optional `order` property that indicates which resolver takes priority.